# Application hangs while getting FFT results

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a loop inside of FFTCalculated event which gets the complex values from after FFT is applied to the raw data.

Base Class

```
 private void FftCalculated(object sender, FftEventArgs e)
    {
        writer = new FFTWriter(path);
            foreach (var a in e.Result)
                writer.WriteValues(a.X,a.Y);  
    }
```

So because it's in the UI thread I wanted to move it to a background thread. So I have created a concurrent queue and enqueue the two values X and Y, and write them to a text file.

```
 private ConcurrentQueue<Tuple<double?, double?>> _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<Tuple<double?,double?>>();
    private string _filePath;
    private Thread _workerThread;
    private bool _isDisposed;

    private void DoWork()
    {
        while (!_isDisposed)
        {
            Tuple<double?, double?> values;
            if (_queue != null && _queue.TryDequeue(out values))
            {
                if(File.Exists(_filePath))
                    try
                    {
                        File.AppendAllText(_filePath, values.Item1 + "," + values.Item2);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) { ex.ToString(); }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!_isDisposed)
        {
            _isDisposed = true;
            _workerThread.Join();
        }
    }

    public FFTWriter(string filePath)
    {
        _filePath = filePath;
        _workerThread = new Thread(DoWork);
        _workerThread.Start();
    }

    public void WriteValues(double? v1, double? v2)
    {
        if (v1.HasValue == true && v2.HasValue == true)
        _queue.Enqueue(new Tuple<double?,double?>(v1.Value, v2.Value));
    }
```

But still, the application hangs. What have I done wrong? I think the problem is in here because the loop is running in the main thread. How can I solve this?

```
 foreach (var a in e.Result)
                writer.WriteValues(a.X,a.Y);
```

Comment: Have a look at [Parallel.ForEach](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwiSvcDVn7bOAhVFtxQKHd7VC18QFggkMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNFtKyC_Jmhh-mC0ZB1Ej94SCG_Xfw&sig2=hIP32g44mAd1iTxrLuiuMQ&bvm=bv.129389765,d.bGg&cad=rja) maybe this solves your problem

Comment: And instead of a ConcurrentQueue you could maybe use a [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) to get rid of the while loop in the DoWork Method. The use of a blockingcollection in a foreach loop should use less resources than the while loop.

Comment: @BoeseB I tried like this but no luck `foreach(var a in e.Result.AsParallel())
    myFFTWriter.WriteValues(a.X,a.Y);` .... Yeah I try that and see now

Comment: Well for each single item you open the file, move to the end, write some data and close the file again (File.AppendAllText will do this open, move, write, close thing). Sounds slow and in fact is much slower than opening once, write all data and close when finished.

Comment: I don't see you doing the `Dispose` anywhere. Also, "application hangs" isn't very useful - have you tried breaking (pause) in the debugger when the application hangs? Where does it hang? Also, a bool flag isn't thread-safe - you really want to use something like `CancellationToken` instead.

Comment: @SirRufo Actually I want the results to be shown in real-time in the spectrum analyzer. For now, I'm just writing them to a text file.

Comment: @Luaan It hangs because of this  `foreach (var a in e.Result)
                writer.WriteValues(a.X,a.Y);` which is an infinite loop where the FFT result is given by the FFT Calculation of the raw data which captured from the microphone and processed through bit converter.

Comment: @Giggity It is not an infinite loop. Result is an array and it can not contain infinite elements

Comment: @SirRufo What I meant was it runs till microphone capturing is set to false. Is there a way where I can raise the event "FFTCalculated" inside a background thread.

Comment: @Giggity In fact it will be triggered again and again until you stop capturing

Comment: @Giggity I just saw generate a new FFTWriter every time the event is raised, wouldn't it be sufficient to only generate the writer at the start of the capture and then use the same instance in every event call until the end of the capture?

Comment: @BoeseB That does not really matter, the code for appending data has to be improved

Comment: @Sir Rufo already improved it in my answer. But he would open the file multiple times if he creates a new FFTWriter in each event call. Instead of open it only once when the first and only FFTWriter is created.This would also reduce the strain on the system from the multiple polling loops in his original code

Answer (score 0):

Putting it all together from the comments your code should look something like this:

Your Code that uses FFTWriter:

```
private FFTWriter _writer;
private void StartNewFFT()
{
    _writer = new FFTWriter(path);
} 

private void FftCalculated(object sender, FftEventArgs e)
{
    _writer.WriteValues(e.Result);  
}
```

The code in the FFTWriter class

```
private BlockingCollection<IEnumerable<FFTResult>> _queue = new BlockingCollection<IEnumerable<FFTResult>>();
private string _filePath;
private Thread _workerThread;
private bool _isDisposed;

private void DoWork()
{
    if(_queue == null)
        return;

    if(!File.Exists(_filePath))
        return;

    using(var file = File.Open(_filePath))
    {
        foreach(var results in _queue)
        {
           try
           {
               foreach(var values in results)
               {
                   if (values.X.HasValue == true && values.Y.HasValue == true)
                       file.WriteLine($"{values.X},{values.Y}");
               }
           }
            catch (Exception ex) { ex.ToString(); }
           }
        }
    }
}

public void Dispose()
{
    if (!_isDisposed)
    {
        _queue.CompleteAdding();
        _isDisposed = true;
        _workerThread.Join();
    }
}

public FFTWriter(string filePath)
{
    _filePath = filePath;
    _workerThread = new Thread(DoWork);
    _workerThread.Start();
}

public void WriteValues(IEnumerable<FFTResult> results)
{
    _queue.Add(new Tuple<double?,double?>(v1.Value, v2.Value));
}
```

**EDIT:** I changed the code to use only one instance of the FFTWriter and moved the outer foreach from the using code into the DoWork() Method so it's executed in the worker Thread.

Comment: I would say that the order matters - but with Parallel.ForEach the items are processed in any order. Maybe the fifth item will be processed before the fourth item.

Comment: @SirRufo Yes, the order matters. I want to visualize the result in the spectrum analyzer. So what can I use instead of Parallel.ForEach?

Comment: You could try to use a normal foreach and add the value in a separat Task with Task.Run(() => writer.WriteValues(a.X, a.Y)); but i am not sure if this preserves the order. But removing the while loop and keeping the file open instead of open for every new entry could already safe enough resources so your application gets speed up and there are no noticeable hangs.

Comment: You coul maybe get another speedup in the event if you add the whole e.Result Collection in the Blocking collection instead iterating in the event and do the Iteration of the values in your Worker Thread